# Loading And Continuing To Add Integers Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am able to save an integer and load it using NSUserdeafaults but when I load up the number and try to continue adding to that number it starts at 0.

Example: I press the button 7 times and switch to a different page. I go back and click load button and it days 7. When I click it again it says 1.

Here is my "press for money" code:

//Press for Money

```
@IBAction func MoneyPress(sender: AnyObject) {

    Money += 1
    var MoneyNumberString:String = String(format: "Dollars:%i", Money)
    self.DollarsLabel.text = (string: MoneyNumberString)
    let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() 
    defaults.setObject(MoneyNumberString, forKey: "money")
    defaults.synchronize()

}
```

Loading Code:

```
@IBAction func LoadTestButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var money = defaults.valueForKey("money") as? String
        DollarsLabel.text! = money!
}
```

Please help if you know how to make it continue adding to that number.

Full Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var MoneyButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var OptionButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var FeelingLuckyButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var TrophiesButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var DollarsLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var BuyNowOne: UIButton!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
var Money = Int(0)

//Press for Money

@IBAction func MoneyPress(sender: AnyObject) {

    Money += 1
    var MoneyNumberString:String = String(format: "Dollars:%i", Money)
    self.DollarsLabel.text = (string: MoneyNumberString)
    let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() 
    defaults.setObject(MoneyNumberString, forKey: "money")
    defaults.synchronize()

}
@IBAction func LoadTestButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var money = defaults.valueForKey("money") as? String
        DollarsLabel.text! = money!
}

}
```

Comment: Where are you originally setting your `Money` variable?

Comment: That is the integer which counts how many times it is clicked.

Comment: Yes, but when do you first set it? I'm assuming you want it to equal the value stored in your NSUserDefaults...

Comment: Could you post that code?

Comment: I posted the full code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting `Money` to 0 when you actually want to set it to contain the value in your `NSUserDefaults`. To do that in your `LoadTestButton` method, try this:

```
@IBAction func LoadTestButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var money = defaults.valueForKey("money") as? String
    DollarsLabel.text! = money!

    // Set "Money" to contain the numbers in your "money"
    // string converted to an Int
    Money = money!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet).toInt()!
}
```

Comment: It is telling me to put ! at the end but when I put it, it tells me to put another one and then it tells me to delete that one and so on. How do I fix this?

Comment: You're probably putting the ! in the wrong places. One sec... I'll update.